# How to reverse my module to go from a Decimal to Hexadecimal in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, hexadecimal

This question is based of the module from here: [How can I convert a hex number to a decimal number in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/472223/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-number-to-a-decimal-number-in-excel#new-answer?newreg=c325fd23a22140e296c364594be7650f)

The Module I am using (from above link) is as such:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function HexadecimalToDecimal(HexValue As String) As Double

    ' If hex starts with 0x, replace it with &H to represent Hex that VBA will understand
    Dim ModifiedHexValue As String
    ModifiedHexValue = Replace(HexValue, "0x", "&H")

    HexadecimalToDecimal = CDec(ModifiedHexValue)

End Function
```

I have it doing:

```
HexadecimalToDecimal(00007FF7BE6B0000)
```

Which gives the correct result of

> "140702028333056"

I would like help on reversing the above module to go from in reverse, so Decimal back to Hexadecimal.

> DecimaltoHexdecimal(140702028333056)

Should result in:

> "00007FF7BE6B0000" *(or obviously "7FF7BE6B0000")*

Any help or guidance would sure be appreciated!

Comment: `Hex(140702028333056)`

Comment: If I do a seperate cell with =Hex(140702028333056) I get the error of: #NAME? 
I also get same error if I do: =DECTOHEX(C7)

Comment: That is the vba code you would use, You will need to create a function that returns the result of that call.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Hex()`

```
Function myDec2Hex(val As Double) As String
    myDec2Hex = Hex(val)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: make sure your number is not a string but a true number.  if that is not it maybe it has to do with version.  I am using office 365.

Comment: (Sorry I could not figure how to post the image like you did, but heres the link: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEpuc.png)

I will try Office 365 Here real quick....